# Construct a probability measure on the union of probability spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal U_{[0,\:1)}$ denote the uniform distribution on $[0,1)$, \begin{equation}\begin{split}&E_d:=[0,1)^d,\\&\mathcal E_d:={\mathcal B\left([0,1)\right)}^{\otimes d},\\&\lambda_d:=\mathcal U_{[0,\:1)}^{\otimes d}\end{split}\end{equation} for $d\in\mathbb N$ and \begin{equation}\begin{split}&E:=\bigcup_{d\in\mathbb N}E_d,\\&\mathcal E':=\sigma(E').\end{split}\end{equation}

> **Question 1**: Can we define a probability measure $\lambda$ on $(E,\mathcal E)$ such that $$\lambda(B)=\lambda_d(B)\;\;\;\text{for all }B\in\mathcal E_d\tag1$$ for all $d\in\mathbb N$?

The measure $$\tilde\lambda(B):=\sum_{d\in\mathbb N}\lambda_d(B\cap E_d)\;\;\;\text{for }B\in\mathcal E\tag2$$ obviously satisfies $(1)$ but it is not a probability measure.

### **EDIT**:

My particular concern is the following: I've got a Borel measurable $u:[0,1)^2\to[0,\infty)$ satisfying $$\int u(x,\;\cdot\;)\:{\rm d}\mathcal U_{[0,\:1)}=1\;\;\;\text{for all }x\in[0,1)\tag3$$ giving rise to the Markov kernel $$U(x,B):=\int_Bu(x,\;\cdot\;)\:{\rm d}\mathcal U_{[0,\:1)}\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in[0,1)\times\mathcal B([0,1)).$$ Now, given an infinite sequence of uniformly distributed samples $x^{(0)}_1,x^{(0)}_2,\ldots$ on $[0,1)$, I'm sampling a finite sequence $x^{(1)}_1,\ldots,x^{(1)}_{d_1}$, $d_1\in\mathbb N$, satisfying $$x^{(1)}_i\sim U\left(x^{(0)}_i,\;\cdot\;\right)\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in\{1,\ldots,d_1\}\tag4.$$ In the next iteration, I'm generating another finite sequence $x^{(2)}_1,\ldots,x^{(2)}_{d_2}$, $d_2\in\mathbb N$, satisfying $$x^{(2)}_i\sim U\left(x^{(1)}_i,\;\cdot\;\right)\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in\{1,\ldots,\min(d_1,d_2)\}\tag5$$ and $$x^{(2)}_i\sim U\left(x^{(0)}_i,\;\cdot\;\right)\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in\{\min(d_1,d_2)+1,\ldots,d_2\}\tag6;$$ and so on.

> At the end of the $n$th iteration, I need to compute the density of sampling $\left(x^{(n)}_i\right)_{1\le i\le d_n}$ (which is conditional on $\left(x^{(n-1)}_i\right)_{1\le i\le d_{n-1}}$).

Since in practice, there are only a finite number $N\in\mathbb N$ of iterations, we may replace $E$ in the question by $\bigcup_{d=1}^{d_{\text{max}}}E_d$, where $$d_{\text{max}}:=\max(d_1,\ldots,d_N).$$ On the other hand, we are not able to compute $d_{\text{max}}$ before the end of the $N$th iteration ...